# Auth->authorize works with beforeFilter but not $components

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In AppController I have

```
public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'profile', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'homepage',
                'action' => 'index',
                'home'
            ),
            'authorize' => 'Controller'
        ),
    );
```

I've tried it with `'authorize'=> array('Controller')` to no avail.

However, the isAuthorized function never gets called.

When I add the line `$this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';` to a specific controller's `beforeFilter`, it works. What's going on?

Comment: Check the value of `$this->Auth->authorize` when you've put it in the components array. Most likely some unshown code is overriding it - or the components array is defined with different values in the child controllers.

Comment: without the line in beforeFilter authorize is set to false. There is only one child controller and it doesn't override authorize.

Comment: it looks like none of the settings are going through could you verify that my appcontroller settings are correct?

Comment: The code in the question looks fine - which means some code that isn't in the question, well, isn't. The easiest solution is to debug the Auth component and see what config it receives and why 'authorize' isn't set appropriately. the [_set](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component.php#L81) call is the one of interest.